# Django Nested Query Performance

Tags: python, django, performance, postgresql, django-queryset

The model I have for a custom form looks like something this.

```
class Form(models.Model):
    # some fields

class FormSection(models.Model):
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form, related_name='section_set')

class FormWidget(models.Model):
    section_set = models.ManyToManyField(FormSection, related_name='widget_set')

class FormEntry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="form_entry_set")
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

class SectionEntry(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(FormSection)
    form_entry = models.ForeignKey(FormEntry, related_name="section_entry_set")

class WidgetEntry(models.Model):
    widget = models.ForeignKey(FormWidget)
    section_entry = models.ForeignKey(SectionEntry, related_name="widget_entry_set")
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

For one of my views, I need to retrieve:

*Given a list of users, get all `FormEntry`s for each user in the list within a certain time period. and for every `FormEntry`, get the form data (WidgetEntry.value)*

and structure it like so in a dictionary.

```
{"<form_entry_pk>": {
        "date": "2015-06-26",
        "<section_name>": {
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_value>"
        },
        "<section_name>": {
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_value>"
        },
        "<section_name>": {
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_entry_value>",
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_entry_value>",
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_entry_value>",
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_entry_value>",
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_entry_value>",
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_entry_value>",
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_entry_value>",
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_entry_value>",
            "<widget_name>": "<widget_entry_value>"
        }
    },
 "<form_entry_pk>": {
        ...
    },
...
}
```

Currently, I am retrieving the data by looping through items in every query set. Something like like this.

```
for user in users:
    form_data = {}    
    form_entries = user.form_entry_set.filter(form=form, date__range=[start_date, end_date]).order_by('date')
    for form_entry in form_entries:
        form_data[form_entry.pk] = {}
        form_data[form_entry.pk]['date'] = form_entry.date
        for section_entry in form_entry.section_entry_set.all():
            form_data[form_entry.pk][section_entry.section.name] = {}
            for widget_entry in section_entry.widget_entry_set.all():
                form_data[form_entry.pk][section_entry.name][widget_entry.widget.name] = widget_entry.value
```

This produces my desired result. But takes up an EXTREMELY long time. Up to 2 minutes in some cases. After some debugging using django-debug-toolbar, I noticed that there are a huge number of duplicate SQL queries. (ie. `4031 queries including 4024 duplicates`)

My question is: What can I do to reduce the number of queries.
I have tried using `defer()` and `only()` (excluded in code to make it more readable). But they don't seem to help all that much.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key here will be to use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) on the initial query. Assuming your models are foreign-keyed correctly, that should resolve all the relations at the top (by following the FKs defined in the models to generate a `JOIN` query behind the scenes).

So the first *query set* then becomes something like this:

```
form_entries = user.form_entry_set.filter(form=form, date__range=[start_date, end_date]).order_by('date').select_related()
```

Then you can access all the columns from the various models from the returned *query set*, which will obviate the need for the nested looping. (You should be able to just loop over the *query set* itself.)

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

[`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) handles additional types of relationships beyond *FK* and *one-to-one*, which it turns out `select_related` is limited to. Since you have a `ManyToManyField` defined in your model, that's likely why `prefetch_related` works better in your specific case.

Comment: Your suggestion didn't seem to work. however, doing `prefetch_related('section_entry_set__widget_entry_set')` seemed to have resolved a large amount of duplicate queries